# Error while generating JAX-WS web-service in RAD 7.5

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, mtom, ibm-rad-7.5

I am trying to generate the Web-Service using RAD7.5 Service generation utility.

I am using annotation on service class as

```
@MTOM
@WebService(serviceName = "WebServiceFileXfr_10", name = "WebServiceFileXfr")
```

and on Web-Service method as

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "servOrderAttchFile")
```

I want to generate the web-service with WSDL file into the project and Web Service deployment descriptor

While selecting **WSDL file into the project** check box, i am getting following error:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.creation.command.CopyWSDLToProjectCommand.correctEndpointAddressesInWSDL(Unknown Source)
  at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.creation.command.CopyWSDLToProjectCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.getNextPage(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleWizardPage.getNextPage(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.popup.DynamicPopupWizard.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

Any help will be highly appreciable

Comment: Have you got `CopyWSDLToProjectCommand` sources? :)

Comment: @dma_k : no, but i have tried top down approch after getting this error to generate the web-service and solve the ugent need. still awaiting for above exception resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The class implementing service should not have an underscore character. 
It seems to be a bug in IRAD. Renaming your service to WebServiceFileXfr would fix the issue.

Comment: I know its too late. But someone else would save sometime :)